# Override View() in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a custom route handler which looks like this:

```
public class SkipstoneMvcHandler: MvcHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{       
    public SkipstoneMvcHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        : base(requestContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return base.BeginProcessRequest(httpContext, callback, state);
    }

    private ControllerBuilder _controllerBuilder;
    internal ControllerBuilder ControllerBuilder
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._controllerBuilder == null)
            {
                this._controllerBuilder = ControllerBuilder.Current;
            }
            return this._controllerBuilder;
        }
        set
        {
            this._controllerBuilder = value;
        }
    }

    private void ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, out IController controller, out IControllerFactory factory)
    {
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
        string requiredString = this.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        factory = this.ControllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory();
        controller = factory.CreateController(this.RequestContext, requiredString);
        if (controller == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find the controller.");
        }
    }

    protected override IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        var companyId = CompanyProvider.CurrentCompanyId(); // Get our current company id

        if (companyId != null)
        {
            var vpp = new SkipstoneVirtualPathProvider(); // Create an instance of our VirtualPathProvider class
            var requestContext = ((MvcHandler)httpContext.Handler).RequestContext; // Get our request context
            var path = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; // Get our requested path

            // If we have a path
            if (path != null)
            {
                var pages = vpp.Pages; // Get all the published pages for this company

                // If we have pages
                if (pages != null)
                {
                    var page = pages.Where(model => model.Path.ToLower() == path.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault(); // Select the page matching our requested path (if any)
                    if (page != null) // If we find the page
                    {
                        requestContext.RouteData.Values["area"] = page.Area; // Set the area
                        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Virtual" + page.Controller; // Set the controller
                        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = page.Name; // And the action
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.BeginProcessRequest(httpContext, callback, state);
    }

    protected override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        base.ProcessRequest(httpContext);
    }
}
```

all this works fine. In my **VirtualControllers** I have something like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        var fileName = string.Empty;

        using (var service = new PageService(new CompanyService(), User.Identity.GetUserId()))
        {
            fileName = await service.View(Request.Url);
        }

        using (var service = new UserService(new CompanyService(), User.Identity.GetUserId()))
        {
            var user = await service.FindByIdAsync(id);
            ViewData["User"] = user;
        }

        if (!fileName.StartsWith(@"/"))
            return View(fileName); // Show the page
        else
            return Redirect(fileName); // Redirect to our page
    }
```

I would prefer to either:

1. Create my own Controller that returns a view based on the URL
2. Override the internal View() method and get my page instead.

I have a base controller which looks like this:

```
public class VirtualBaseController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ViewResult> View(string masterName, object model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            base.ViewData.Model = model;
        }

        using (var service = new PageService(new CompanyService()))
        {
            var viewname = await service.View(Request.Url);

            return this.View(viewname, masterName, model);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here is when **return View()** is called in my controllers that inherit from **VirtualBaseController** instead of it looking for a physical file, it will return the virtual file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but have you tried http://attributerouting.net/. It is not exactly clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish.